# при ховере не выделять вложеные элементы списка вместе с его родителем

Tags: css

Как при ховере не выделять вложеные элементы?

Вот пример кода:

```
 ul.left-menu>li:hover{
        background:#f5a51a; 
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9c4q72uj/    --код полностью

то, что хочу получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите поправить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обновил. Можно подсвечивать не "li", а саму ссылку "a"

```css
body {
  background: #05294f;
}
ul.left-menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
ul.left-menu li {
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
ul.left-menu li ul li a:before {
  content: "•";
  color: #dadada;
  font-size: 21px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
ul.left-menu li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul.left-menu li a:hover {
  background: #f5a51a;
}
```

```html
<ul class="left-menu">
  <li><a href="/0.html">1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/1.html">1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/1.html">1.1</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="/2.html">1.2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/3.html">3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/4.html">4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/5.html">2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/6.html">3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: благодарю,я поясню: вложеные элементы тоже можно выделять, но так, чтобы они не выделялись вместе с родителем(то как у меня сейчас)

Comment: Тогда в стилях заменить "ul.left-menu > li > a:hover" на "ul.left-menu li a:hover". Обновил код

Answer (score 2):

```css
body > ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

li {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

a:hover:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1.5em; /* same as line-height */
  background: silver;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="left-menu">
  <li><a href="/0.html">1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/1.html">1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/1.html">1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="/2.html">1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/3.html">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="/4.html">4</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/5.html">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/6.html">3</a></li> 
</ul>
```

```css
li {
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<ul class="left-menu">
  <li><a href="/0.html">1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/1.html">1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/1.html">1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="/2.html">1.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/3.html">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="/4.html">4</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/5.html">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/6.html">3</a></li> 
</ul>
```